# Linux why does yum say up-to-date when newer versions available?

Tags: yum, util-linux

I am trying to install an up-to-date version (2.19) of  `util-linux` to get `lsblk` but yum doesn't find it:

```
[Harry@SN031568820668 ~]$ sudo yum install util-linux
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Package util-linux-ng-2.16.2-9.fc12.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Please, is there a way round this? I am using Fedora 12 (until tomorrow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say why you need this new version of `lsblk` but there are a variety of reasons why there might be a newer version of a package available yet you cannot update to that version.

1. The packages for this new version may not be available in a YUM repo that you're subscribed to, or they may not even be available
2. You may have some other package(s) that require a shared dependency with `util-linux`. In order to move up to this newer version of `util-linux` this dependency needs to be upgraded, and the other package cannot move up to this new dependency.
3. There are other reasons...

When confronted with this type of situation you generally have 2 paths to go. You can download the SRC package of `util-linux` and attempt to rebuild it using your system's set of libraries (can be a difficult path), or download the actual source of `util-linux` and attempt to build it outside of RPM's management.

If compiling something is completely out of your comfort zone then take a look at these other alternatives that I mention in your other U&L Q&A titled: "[Linux: what is on each of my hard drives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114204/7453)".

Comment: Thank you for that, @sim. It's because `lsblk` was not in `util-linux` until v2.19... or so.

Comment: @HarryWeston - I'm almost positive that you can download `lsblk`'s source and compile it manually. I seem to remember doing this a few months ago on FC14 to see some changes to that package when answering a Q here. It's not too complicated if you need it.

Comment: @HarryWeston - this was the Q: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84357/how-to-install-lsblk-on-centos-5/84360#84360

Comment: +1 `util-linux` is distributed by kernel.org: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/ I recommend you build this and install it into `/usr/local`, which will be the default.  This way you can make the system prefer the new version by *appending* `/usr/local` to `$PATH` (I think fedora does this) or conversely removing it.  `make uninstall` should also work for that package (*if* you leave your build directory as is post configure), but again, **don't** install it over top of the existing distro version.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Fedora 12 is *long, long, long* past end-of-life. No more updated packages, ever.

Backup your data and configuration, and install a new Fedora (currently 20). No, there is no update path available (not any reasonable one, at least). But Fedora 20 will EOL in a year or so.

If you really need stability for such a long stretch, consider migrating to [CentOS](http://www.centos.org) (6 is scheduled for EOL in 2020, 7 should be out soonish).